# VS Breakpoint overjump

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

There is a strange problem I'm stuck with about breaking into code. The structure where this happens for me looks as following:

```
public partial class TopClass : SomeBaseClass
{
    protected override void ShowDetail(ResultItem resultitem)
    {
        // Trying to break here without success
        string test = "should be able to break here, shouldnt it?";
    }
}


public partial class SomeBaseClass : ...
{
    protected virtual void ExecutionIncomingHere()
    {
        // .. some stuff going on
        ShowDetail(resItem);
    }

    protected virtual void ShowDetail(ResultItem resultitem)
    {   // empty
    }
}
```

The problem I've got is easier to just show off. Check this:

**Breakpoint is set.**
[image]

**VS only breaks inside my base (why ever)**
[image]

I guess this arrow indicates, that I'm currently inside that method. By why cant I debug inside `ShowDetail()`? When going for `F11` it continues inside the base class. So my `TopClass` is never entered step-by-step.

I tried searching on google for at least 1 hour without any success. I hope some of you can clear that out.

Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Are you debugging optimized code?

Comment: Check if you have Optimize Code enabled. You can find it here: Project properties -> Build, section General, `[ ] Optimize Code`.

Comment: @SLaks Oh.. even after hours of being annoyed a point I havnt checked. Ill do so now.

Comment: @PeterB The base is inside another project (library). I guess my `TopClass`-project is the one I should check!?

Comment: Goes for the project that owns the file in which you try to set the breakpoint.

Comment: @PeterB ok that truly solved my problem hah. Thanks a lot! Is this even worth being saved as a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have "Optimize code" checked.
To remove this go to the properties of you project, then click on the "Build" tab on the left hand side. There you should see the "Optimize code" check box. If this is checked, uncheck it. That should fix your issue.